# Simple odoo many2one multiple context returns no value

Tags: xml, odoo

I have a many2one field in sale.order.line.
It is pointing to a custom model with relations to product.product and res.partner.

I want this new field to return the name of a record in the custom model based on the product and the customer (in sale.order.line).

I added `<field name="x_product_customer_reference" string="Product Customer Reference" context="{'default_x_customer_id': order_partner_id, 'default_x_product_id': product_id}"/>` in the sale.order.line.form.readonly XML view.

But the new field stays empty. Why is it not working? ...

Comment: If possible can you please share your sample code here.

Comment: I used odoo developer mode on Saas.
Here is XML view in sale.order.line
```<field name="x_product_customer_reference" string="Product Customer Reference" context="{'default_x_customer_id': order_partner_id, 'default_x_product_id': product_id}"/>```
My custom model x_customer_product_reference has two many2one fields, ```x_customer_id``` and ```x_product_id```.

Comment: also domains are working well, but will not work to set a default value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please write the below code

```
<field name="x_product_customer_reference" string="Product Customer Reference" context="{'default_x_customer_id': partner_id, 'default_x_product_id':product_id}"/>
```

Please note that partner_id field should be there in sale order line, so please create an invisible partner_id field in sale order line otherwise please follow the below code

```
<field name="x_product_customer_reference" string="Product Customer Reference" context="{'default_x_customer_id': parent.partner_id, 'default_x_product_id':product_id}"/>
```